# Bound the product of any continuous function

Tags: continuity, self-learning, upper-lower-bounds, products

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a$ (either positive or negative or zero) be a constant also in the domain of $f$. I would like to be able to bound the product $f(x + a)f(x)$.

Is it true that for **any continuous function** and **any points $x$ and $a$** at least one of the following statements will be true:

1. $f(x)^2 \leq |f(x + a)f(x)| \leq f(x + a)^2$
2. $f(x+a)^2 \leq |f(x + a)f(x)| \leq f(x)^2$
3. $f(x+a)^2 \leq |f(x + a)f(x)| \leq f(x+a)^2$
4. $f(x)^2 \leq |f(x + a)f(x)| \leq f(x)^2$

Graphically, it makes sense for me but I am struggling to prove it mathematically.

Comment: No, I do not think it is true. The left and right hand side is always non negative, whereas the middle part can easily be negative

Comment: I added the absolute value.

Comment: We can assume $|f(x)|\leq |f(x+a)|$ then $f(x)^2\leq |f(x)f(x+a)|\leq f(x+a)^2$ does hold, so for fixed $x, x+a$ one of those holds (i.e. either 1 or 2), this has nothing to do with continuity, but not necessarily one of them for all $x, x+a$ (order of quantifiers is important here).

Comment: Can you find a specific counterexample?

Comment: Any function for which we can find $x, a$ with $|f(x)|>|f(x+a)|$ and $x, a$ with $|f(x)| < |f(x+a)|$ holding will be a counter-example. Say, $f(x) = |x|$

Comment: In the case $f(x) = |x|$, I cannot find a pair (x,a) such that one of them is not true.

Comment: *For fixed* $x, x+a$ *one 1-4 does hold* as I mentioned above. In fact 1 or 2. But you can't always pick one of 1-4 and say it holds for all $x, x+a$. That's what I said above